# how to get dynamic values inside a xsl:comment

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

This below code doesnot load the dynamic value of $URL_PREFIX as it is in cdata.
Please let me know how to get dynamic values inside a comment.

```
    <xsl:comment><![CDATA[[if gte IE 9]>    
        <link href="$URL_PREFIX/Static/resources/common/css/redesign/new-ie.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <![endif]]]></xsl:comment>
```

I want the value $URL_PREFIX.

Comment: What output are you trying to generate? And from what input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll need to break up your `CDATA` like this...

```
    <xsl:comment><![CDATA[[if gte IE 9]>   
    <link href="]]><xsl:value-of select="$URL_PREFIX"/><![CDATA[/Static/resources/common/css/redesign/new-ie.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]]]></xsl:comment>
```

Full example...

**XSLT 1.0** (applied to any XML input)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="URL_PREFIX" select="'http://foo.com'"/>
        <xsl:comment><![CDATA[[if gte IE 9]>   
        <link href="]]><xsl:value-of select="$URL_PREFIX"/><![CDATA[/Static/resources/common/css/redesign/new-ie.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <![endif]]]></xsl:comment>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]>   
        <link href="http://foo.com/Static/resources/common/css/redesign/new-ie.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <![endif]-->
```